# unable to update single item background color in Listview.builder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

Im working on flutter listview.builder I just want to change background colour of 3 items in Row widget at where user clicks but its changing colours of all the items in listview. just want to change color at specific index based on user click. here is my code...

```
    import 'dart:convert';

    import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:fluttergyancare/ColorLoader3.dart';
    import 'package:fluttergyancare/Models/AddAttendanceModel.dart';
    import 'package:fluttergyancare/Models/serializers.dart';
    import 'package:gradient_app_bar/gradient_app_bar.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    class AddAttendance extends StatelessWidget {
      final String id;
      final String section;
      final String school;
      final String Class;

      AddAttendance({this.id, this.section, this.school, this.Class});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFEEEEEE),
          appBar: GradientAppBar(
            title: Text('Normal'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColorStart: Color(0xFFFF9844),
            backgroundColorEnd: Color(0xFFFD7267),
          ),
          body: FutureBuilderUI(
            id: id,
            section: section,
            school: section,
            Class: Class,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    Future<AddAttendanceModel> call(http.Client client, String id, String section,
        String school, String Class) async {
      var send =
          await http.post("http://localhost/app/api/get_students", body: {
        "teacher_id": "1",
        "class_id": id,
        "section": section,
        "school_name": school,
        "Class": Class,
      });

      return compute(parseJson, (send.body));
    }

    AddAttendanceModel parseJson(String json) {
      final jsonStr = jsonDecode(json);
      AddAttendanceModel article = standardSerializers.deserializeWith(
          AddAttendanceModel.serializer, jsonStr);
      return article;
    }

    class FutureBuilderUI extends StatelessWidget {
      final String id;
      final String section;
      final String school;
      final String Class;
      FutureBuilderUI({this.id, this.section, this.school, this.Class});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder<AddAttendanceModel>(
          future: call(http.Client(), id, section, school, Class),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
              case ConnectionState.active:
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(
                  child: ColorLoader3(
                    radius: 25.0,
                    dotRadius: 10.0,
                  ),
                );
              case ConnectionState.done:
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                print(snapshot.data.studentsInfo.length.toString() +
                    " StudentsInfo Length");
                if (snapshot.data.studentsInfo.length != 0) {
                  return snapshot.hasData
                      ? AddAttendanceUI(students: snapshot.data)
                      : Container();
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text("No..")),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
            }
            return null;

    //          return ListView.builder(
    //            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    //              return ListTile(
    //                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].status),
    //              );
    //            },
    //          );
          },
        );
      }
    }

    class AddAttendanceUI extends StatefulWidget {
      final AddAttendanceModel students;
      AddAttendanceUI({this.students});
      @override
      _AddAttendanceUIState createState() => _AddAttendanceUIState();
    }

    class _AddAttendanceUIState extends State<AddAttendanceUI> {
      var pColor = Colors.green;
      var aColor = Colors.grey;
      var nColor = Colors.grey;
      int _onSelectedindex = 0;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.students.studentsInfo.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Card(
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    SizedBox(width: 10),

                    Spacer(),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: pSelector(),
                            onTap: () {
                              print(index);
                              setState(() {
    //                            final a = widget.students.studentsInfo
    //                                .where((l) =>
    //                                    l.id ==
    //                                    widget.students.studentsInfo[index].id)
    //                                .toList();
                                _onSelectedindex = index;

                                aColor = Colors.grey;
                                pColor = Colors.green;
                                nColor = Colors.grey;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 12),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  print(widget.students.studentsInfo[index].id);
                                  aColor = Colors.red;
                                  pColor = Colors.grey;
                                  nColor = Colors.grey;
                                });
                              },
                              child: aSelector()),
                          SizedBox(width: 12),
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: nSelector(),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                print(widget.students.studentsInfo[index].id);
                                aColor = Colors.grey;
                                pColor = Colors.grey;
                                nColor = Colors.orange;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            });
      }

      hello() {}

      Widget pSelector() {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: pColor,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              child: DottedBorder(
                strokeWidth: 2.5,
                borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "A",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget aSelector() {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: aColor,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              child: DottedBorder(
                strokeWidth: 2.5,
                borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "B",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget nSelector() {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: nColor,
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              child: DottedBorder(
                strokeWidth: 2.5,
                borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "C",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

see Images below                                                                                                  [image1](https://punjablotteries.in/screenshot2.png)                                    [image2](https://punjablotteries.in/screenshot1.png)                                    [image3](https://punjablotteries.in/screenshot.png)

I tried to attach streamBuilder with each single item in listview but not working.

I expect when user taps on A/B/C only at that index colours should be change but its changing colours of all the items

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same 3 variables pColor, aColor, nColor for all the items. You should have a list or a map of these variables, one for each item. Or create a separate widget to handle these variables internally on that widget.